I want to test my /token path with FastAPI
I developed my API with FastAPI. I use aiomysql for my database connections with pools and cursors.
Here is my code in my main.py file:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from .internals.settings import get_config
from .internals.tags import tags_metadata
from .internals.postgres import init_postgres
from .services.reservation import init_sqllite, reload_seat_to_unlock
import aiomysql


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    config = get_config()
    app.state.pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(
        host=config.APP_DB_HOST,
        port=config.APP_DB_PORT,
        user=config.APP_DB_USER,
        password=config.APP_DB_PASSWORD,
        db=config.APP_DB_DATABASE,
    )
    init_sqllite(app)
    reload_seat_to_unlock(app)
    init_postgres(app)
    yield


app = FastAPI(
    lifespan=lifespan,
    title="Actifastage",
    summary="Actistages JsonAPI",
    version="1.3.2",
    contact={
        "name": "educacode",
        "url": "https://www.educacode.com",
        "email": "contact@educacode.com",
    },
    openapi_tags=tags_metadata,
)

client = TestClient(app)

I created a test folder with a test_login.py file and here is my code:
from app.main import client


async def test_login(user={"username": "unit-test", "password": "unittest"}):
    response = client.post("/token", data=user)
    assert response.status_code == 200


When I run the "pytest" command I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'pool'
Here, an exemple of a database request i do:
async def get_user(username: str) -> Optional[UserInDB]:
    async with app.state.pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor(aiomysql.DictCursor) as cur:
            await cur.execute(
                "SELECT id, username, password, is_active FROM sf_guard_user WHERE username=%s AND is_active=TRUE",
                username,
            )
            res = await cur.fetchone()
            await conn.commit()

            res = UserInDB.read(res) if res else None
            return res

Can you try to explain me how resolve this problem ?
Thanks
I try to redeclare lifespan to initiate a new app.state.pool but i already have same problem.

Have you tried using Option 2 of this answer instead?
